# Powershell - having trouble building a string for use in an MS Graph odata statement

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I realise this is probably annoyingly simple for some people here and I'm missing something obvious but I'm having trouble trying to build a string into a PowerShell MS Graph API request (assume all the code for auth token, etc. is working).

This sample works:

```
$intuneDeviceId = 'deadbeef-1234-1234-1234-deadbeef1234' 
$deviceCategoryReqBody = '{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/98769876-9876-9876-9876-9876543210"}' 
$patchDeviceReqBody = '{}'
#calling the PUT method to update device category for that specific device
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/$intuneDeviceId/deviceCategory/`$ref" -Headers $authToken -Method Put -Body $deviceCategoryReqBody
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/$intuneDeviceId" -Headers $authToken -Method Patch -Body $patchDeviceReqBody
```

That works as expected for a single device and single device category but I'm trying to build a module that can be called with parameters for device ID and device category ID.

What does not work is trying to replace the hard coded GUIDs with strings from my parameters; I simply can't build a working string in the odata statement:

```
param([string] $intuneDeviceId,
    [string] $DeviceCategoryID,
    [string] $User)
{ ... } # cutting out all the un-needed auth code stuff to keep this short
$devicereqput = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/$($DeviceCategoryID)"
$deviceCategoryReqBody = '{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/$($DeviceCategoryID)"}' #update the deviceCateg id
$patchDeviceReqBody = '{}'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/$intuneDeviceId/deviceCategory/`$ref" -Headers $authToken -Method Put -Body $deviceCategoryReqBody
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/$intuneDeviceId" -Headers $authToken -Method Patch -Body $patchDeviceReqBody
```

This fails, and examining the strings at this point shows that the `$devicecategoryreqbody` string I'm using in the OData statement shows a URL with a literal `"$devicecategoryID"` at the end instead of the value of that string.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the single quotes will allow for string literals. This means `$($DeviceCategoryID)` will never expand as a variable and it will remain as is. You should try replacing the outer single quotes with double quotes. Then backtick escape all of the inner double quotes. `$deviceCategoryReqBody = "{\`"@odata.id\`":\`"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/$($DeviceCategoryID)\`"}"`

Comment: Yes, something like that ought to work. I'll give it a go, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) correctly identified the problem with missing expansion in single quoted string.

I'd use

- the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to insert variables,
  To escape a literal curly brace in a -f format string double it ([hint by EBGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27257333/how-do-i-escape-curly-braces-in-powershell#comment42988576_27257380))
- [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) to pass parameters

---

```
param([string] $intuneDeviceId,
      [string] $DeviceCategoryID,
      [string] $User)
{...}
$MSgraph               = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement'
$devicereqput          = '"{0}/deviceCategories/{1}"' -f $MSgraph,$DeviceCategoryID

$deviceCategoryReqBody = '{{"@odata.id":{0}}}' -f $devicereqput      #update the deviceCateg id
$patchDeviceReqBody    = '{}'

$params = @{
    Uri     = "{0}/managedDevices/{1}/deviceCategory/`$ref" -f $MSgraph,$intuneDeviceId
    Headers = $authToken
    Method  = Put
    Body    = $deviceCategoryReqBody
}
Invoke-RestMethod @params

$params = @{
    Uri     = "{0}/managedDevices/{1}" -f $MSgraph,$intuneDeviceId
    Headers = $authToken
    Method  = Patch 
    Body    = $patchDeviceReqBody
}
Invoke-RestMethod @params
```